# How to use MutationObserver with an Object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
mind = {
    queries: [],
    actions: []
};
```

and I update `queries` and `actions` according to another function.

I wanted to detect every time they're being updated and changed, and i've heard about `MutationObserver`, so I tried to call it:

```
var muob = (window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver);
var ob = new muob(function(m) {
    console.log('It works!');
});
ob.observe(mind, { subtree: true });
```

But it doesn't work. I get in return:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: MutationObserver is used to observe changes of DOM nodes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MutationObserver is only something that works for *DOM elements*, not objects:

```js
var ob = new MutationObserver(function(m) {
    console.log('It works!');
});
ob.observe(mind, { childList: true });

mind.textContent = 'foo';
```

```html
<div id="mind"></div>
```

For what you're doing, you can make the `queries` and `actions` properties have methods to update the arrays instead, eg:

```js
const mind = {
  _queries: [],
  _actions: [],
  queries: {
    push(...args) {
      console.log('Push detected');
      mind._queries.push(...args);
    },
    get() {
      return mind._queries;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    push(...args) {
      console.log('Push detected');
      mind._actions.push(...args);
    },
    get() {
      return mind._actions;
    }
  }
};

mind.queries.push('foo');
console.log(mind.queries.get());
```

Or, using a Proxy:

```js
const handler = {
  set(obj, prop, newVal) {
    console.log('Change detected');
    return obj[prop] = newVal;
  },
  get(obj, prop) {
    return obj[prop];
  }
};

const mind = {
  queries: new Proxy([], handler),
  actions: new Proxy([], handler),
};

mind.queries.push('foo');
console.log(mind.queries);
```

(the above snippet logs `Change detected` twice because it has to update both the `0` property on the array *and* change the array's `.length`)

Still, this is pretty odd - it would be much more elegant if, at the location in the code where you change the array, you also call another function (the `It works!` part) to indicate an update has occurred.

Comment: With those `get` methods, you're going to need a Proxy. Otherwise, they can be directly modified without notification.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. can I use `console.log()` on my variable in the callback function? example: `Mutation...(function(variable) { console.log(variable); });` ?

Comment: @user11247237 The setters and getters are functions, so you can log their arguments as needed. Eg `console.log('newVal', newVal);`

Answer (score 0):

`MutationObserver` is for DOM elements, not JavaScript objects.

There is no equivalent for JavaScript objects,¹ but you can use a combination of [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects and accessor properties to get a notification of any change to those arrays. You'd use the Proxy to know when the arrays were modified, and by making `x` and `y` accessor properties, you could know when they were changed (and use that as the opportunity to wrap them in proxies).

Here's a rough sketch:

```js
const mind = (() => {
    function wrap(array) {
        return new Proxy(array, {
            set(target, propName, value, receiver) {
                beforeChange(target, propName, value, receiver);
                const result = Reflect.set(target, propName, value);
                afterChange(target, propName, value, receiver);
                return result;
            }
            // ...you may want other traps here...
        });
    }

    function beforeChange(target, name, value, receiver) {
        console.log("beforeChange", name, value);
    }

    function afterChange(target, name, value, receiver) {
        console.log("afterChange", name, value);
    }

    let queries = wrap([]);
    let actions = wrap([]);
    return {
        get queries() {
            return queries;
        },
        set queries(value) {
            beforeChange(queries, "*queries*", value);
            queries = wrap(value);
            afterChange(queries, "*queries*", value);
        },
        get actions() {
            return queries;
        },
        set queries(value) {
            beforeChange(queries, "*actions*", value);
            queries = wrap(value);
            afterChange(queries, "*actions*", value);
        }
    };
})();

mind.queries.push(1);
mind.actions.push("two");
console.log(mind.actions);
mind.actions[0] = "TWO";
console.log(mind.actions);
mind.queries = [];
mind.queries[10] = "ten";
console.log(mind.queries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

---

¹ For a brief time there was going to be `Object.observe`, but it was abandoned in favor of Proxy.